# I am facing issue in storing uid in database

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

This is error

> error getting token java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> com.google.firebase.internal.api.FirebaseNoSignedInUserException:
> Please sign in before trying to get a token. W/NetworkRequest(10820):
> no auth token for request W/NetworkRequest(10820): No App Check token
> for request. E/flutter (10820):
> [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled
> Exception: Null check operator used on a null value E/flutter (10820):
> #0      _signupState.build. (package:ecommerce/Auth/signup.dart:161:28) E/flutter (10820):
>  E/flutter (10820):

I think error is in uid because when use id it signup successfully. If my code is wrong then please tell how I can store.
This is my code

```
final uid =auth.currentUser!.uid ;
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: emailcontroller.text.toString(), password: passcontroller.text.toString()).then((signin){
  ref.doc(uid).set({
    "id":uid,
"name":namecontroller.text.toString(),
    "email":emailcontroller.text.toString(),
    "password":passcontroller.text.toString(),
    "phone":phonecontroller.text.toString(),
    "imageurl":url1.toString()
  })
```

Comment: i think the token is expired login again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `uid` before signUp in App. Try this code:

```
var uid;
await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: emailcontroller.text.toString(), password: passcontroller.text.toString()).then((signin){
uid =auth.currentUser!.uid ;
  ref.doc(uid).set({
    "id":uid,
"name":namecontroller.text.toString(),
    "email":emailcontroller.text.toString(),
    "password":passcontroller.text.toString(),
    "phone":phonecontroller.text.toString(),
    "imageurl":url1.toString()
  })
```